# Python Race Condition making directories error

Tags: python, directory

The problem I'm having was talked about back in 2012 but the code is no longer supported on the newer versions of python. My 
current code is

```
import os
a = os.getcwd()

people_name = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']


def create_names():
    for names in people_name:
        os.makedirs(a + '/'+ names, exist_ok=True)

create_names()
```

I tried with and without the "exist_ok=True".  That was one of the suggestions in the 2012 post so I thought I'll give it a try.

Without the exist_ok=True I get a "file already exist Error".  When I run the code using the exit_ok=True I get this weird msg

```
;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Python version 3.5
Any ideas why the directories are not being created?  Is there something I need to add to the code?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is? Your last "error" message doesn't seem to relate to the code you've posted.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @PeterGibson Python version 3.5

Answer (score 2):

os.mkdir() would make more sense here.

```
for names in people_name:
    if not os.path.exists(names):
        os.mkdir(names)
```

Comment: Same problem :/  It gives me the FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: if I use it

Comment: see my edit, you need to check if the folder exists first